# Firebase Crashlytics Custom Email/Slack Headers

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

Currently, Crashlytics send an email/slack with:

[image]

Stacktrace Summary, App package name, Platform(Android), Version.

And complete details opens up only after going to the Crashlytics dashboard through the crash link in the email.

But what if we need to send the flavour/environment as well. Though it can be detected from package name itself. But there must be a way to add a new key value. Like

1. Number of occurrences of the error
2. Environment/Flavour of the app

Either we can add another header key, or if we can insert the environment before the activity name in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Firebase here. Currently there isn't a way to customize these notifications, but I'll share your desire with this internally.

Comment: Is the customisation available now?

Comment: Slight customizations are available via Firebase Functions, but not what was requested above: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/crashlytics-events

Comment: is this available now? I would love to see my build version along with app version. This would provide a lot of clarity.